# create simple function returning value from table

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to make very simple function returning lenght of text in cell of a table (in Workbench), but still getting error 1064 when trying to run it, though I think everything is good in commands below. Where is the problem?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS how_long;
CREATE FUNCTION how_long(thing varchar(20)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE sth INT;
    SELECT length(word) INTO sth FROM things WHERE name=thing;
  RETURN sth;
END;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be setting delimiters see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already know. It was really stupid, but I tried to do it just by new sql table, not by >function and >right_click > create

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
delimiter |
drop function if exists how_long|
create function how_long(thing varchar(20)) returns int
no sql
deterministic
begin
   return length(thing);
end|
select how_long('hello')|
```

but why don't you just use the native function `length()` ?